# How can I use `\pgfmathresult` as x-coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I need to use `\pgfmathparse{floor(\textwidth/2)}` as one of x-coordinates of a path but I get an error.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,varwidth=100mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[draw](0,0)--(\pgfmathparse{floor(\textwidth/2)},0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use `\pgfmathparse` there. You are getting a bunch of errors. Put `\pgfmathparse` outside of the `\draw` command (before) then use `\pgfmathresult`.

Comment: There is no need to call `\pfmathparse`, `\documentclass[margin=5mm,varwidth=100mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[draw](0,0)--({floor(\textwidth/2)},0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the reasons why I *really* like Ti*k*Z is because of its parser. It parses the coordinates automatically. All you need to do is

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,varwidth=100mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[draw](0,0)--({floor(\textwidth/2)},0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The only thing you have to watch out for are things like the brackets, which you have to put in a braces, i.e. `\path[draw](0,0)--(floor(\textwidth/2),0);` will give an error because Ti*k*Z does not know which brackets delimit the coordinates. Another thing you may want to consider is that Ti*k*Z will convert these units to points. So `floor` may or may not give you what you want. However, you can always convert things to the units you want to work in, e.g. `\path[draw](0,0)--({floor((\textwidth/2)*1pt/1cm)*1cm},0);`.